# Can't use tikz-pic together with tikzscale

Tags: tikz-pic, tikzscale

I am trying to use a tikz-picture containing pic-templates together with tikzscale, but when including the image via `\includegraphics[]{}` I get a variety of errors. On the other hand, when including it via `\input{}` the process works fine.
My main file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}%\textsl{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\begin{document}
%   \input{test_pic.tikz} %Works
    \begin{figure}[htpb]%Does not work
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{test_pic.tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and my tikz-file is

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,quotes,positioning}
\tikzset{
    demo_box/.pic = {
        \coordinate (-in) at (0, 0);
        \draw[pic actions] (0, -0.5) rectangle (0.5, 0.5);
        \node[align=center, below] at(0, -0.75) {\tikzpictext};
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[fill=white] (demo_node) at (2, 0) {demo_box};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the current configuration I get the error

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@xc 
        
l.11 ...fill=white] (demo_node) at (2, 0) {demo_box}
```

When changing the second to last line in my tikz-file to

```
\pic["Demo", fill=white] (demo_node) at (2, 0) {demo_box};
```

I get the following error instead:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"Demo"' and I am going to
 ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Is there any way I can combine `pic` and `tikzscale`? And where do those errors come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]%Does work <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \centering
    \includegraphics{test_pic.tikz}
\end{figure}
```

Having `\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,quotes,positioning}` in the preamble instead of part of `test_pic.tikz`, or not using at all, you will get a prior error to line #11 of the `.tikz`, in the main file, line #15, pointing to the cause `! Package tikzscale Error: Requested to scale unscalable graphic.`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,quotes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\centering

\input{test_pic.tikz} %Works (remove \usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,quotes,positioning})

%   \begin{figure}[htpb]%Does not work
%       \centering
%       \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{test_pic.tikz}% line #15 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%   \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htpb]%Does work <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \centering
    \includegraphics{test_pic.tikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```